# SonarQube no new lines on merge request in Android gitlab project

Tags: android, gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

My goal is to send full JaCoCo report to SonarQube and analyze it through gitlab. My full command is like:

```
gradlew \
-Dsonar.host.url=$URL \
-Dsonar.pullrequest.key=$NUMBER \
-Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=branch_name \
-Dsonar.pullrequest.base=main \
-Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true \
sonarqube
```

When I'm using my local command line is everything fine. Sonar shows properly new lines with code coverage in pull request. Strange thing is, when I'm using **the same** command by gitlab-ci it doesn't show any new lines.

How can I fix my pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I ran my all process with `--debug` mode, like this:

```
gradlew \
-Dsonar.host.url=$URL \
-Dsonar.pullrequest.key=$NUMBER \
-Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=branch_name \
-Dsonar.pullrequest.base=main \
-Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true \
sonarqube --debug > output.txt
```

It's helpfull to obtain file as artifact in short mode:

```
  artifacts:
    name: "sonar_logs"
    paths:
      - output.txt
```

and problem was less complicated as I thought:

```
2021-09-12T13:06:03.370+0200 [WARN] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Could not find ref 'refs/heads/master' in refs/heads, refs/remotes, refs/remotes/upstream or refs/remotes/origin
```

to fix this, I've just added line before my "sonarqube" goal:

```
script:
- git fetch origin master:master
- gradlew \
-Dsonar.host.url=$URL \
-Dsonar.pullrequest.key=$NUMBER \
-Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=branch_name \
-Dsonar.pullrequest.base=main \
-Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true \
sonarqube
```

As job is closed environment, It doesn't see any other branches like master. You have to manually fetch master branch, then SonarQube can compare differences and show new lines.